# how do i start printing after previous line printed on page using oracle report developer 2000?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apps

I am using oracle developer 2000 to make a report,
the requirement is to print the data on page then again print after the printed line.
I have saved the total number of line printed but i don't know how to start print after that printed lines?
Please suggest solution.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, can you give some sample data and using that describe, what results you want to achieve.

Comment: We need just like passbook printing in banks (india)

Comment: If this is for Oracle E Biz suite, can you not configure a one of the passbook printers ? how else do you want to achieve this ? A normal printer will not work, since you will have to write native code to interface with the printer to scan and then print after a specific point.

Comment: We are using Epson PLQ20 passbook printer and Oracle Report Builder 6i for report development. 
Is it possible to print blank row before printing main content?

Comment: that should be possible to create in the report builder paper layout, isnt it.